# iPhone NSString drawAtPoint linebreakmodeWordWrap

Tags: uitableview, nsstring, line-breaks, drawrect

Since I had a very slow scrolling tableView  I'm now trying to catch up with the direct draw method, similiar to the Tweetie App sample or Apples TableViewSuite code.

So right now I'm struggling to draw NSString with more than one line.
I'm using the `[NSString drawAtPoint: forWidth: withFont: linebreakMode:]` method, and it "breaks" the line, but it doesn't show the second line, it just cuts the rest of the string off.

Is this a normal behavior and what can be the solution to multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
[yourString drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode]
```

Comment: Where do you put this code - view controller or a views drawRect: ?

Comment: In your view's drawRect:(CGRect)rect method. You should use the rect parameter to calculate the rectangle that will be passed to the drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode: method.